# LG G2 D802 (NO DOWNLOAD MODE) after Flashing

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, android-versions, lg-g2

I'm am trying to install Lollipop on my LG G2 D802. I have used TWRP to install it. All goes well but it says on boot that `fastboot` mode started. So I reverted back, but now I have recovery with no Download Mode.

Can anyone tell me how I can get my Download Mode back?